# jQuery - Script not inserting div after last row of items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to insert a div after each row of elements. The trouble is, it isn't adding one after the last row of elements unless the row is full (Ie; If the row only has 1 or 2 elements, the div doesn't get added, but if there are 3 elements, it does).

Can anyone help me troubleshoot?

Here is the function;

```
function separateRows(parent, children) {
    var panelHtml = '\
        <div class="team-member__panel"> \
        </div> \
    ';
    var $elems = $(parent + ">" + children);
    var top = $elems.first().offset().top;
    var n = 1;
    while( n < $elems.length && $elems.eq(n).offset().top == top )
        n++;
    var $div = $(panelHtml);
    $div.insertAfter(parent + ">" + children + ":nth-child(" + n + "n)");
}
separateRows(".team-members", ".team-member");
```

Here is a fiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/zbqq782m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the div after each nth element.

So for n=3 you add it after third and sixth element. If you have eight elements, then there is no more element to insert after (like a nineth element).

In this case you would need to add it after the last element manually:

```
function separateRows(parent, children) {
    var panelHtml = '\
        <div class="team-member__panel"> \
        </div> \
    ';
    var $elems = $(parent + ">" + children);
    var top = $elems.first().offset().top;
    var n = 1;
    while( n < $elems.length && $elems.eq(n).offset().top == top )
        n++;
    var $div = $(panelHtml);
    $div.insertAfter(parent + ">" + children + ":nth-child("+n+"n)");

    if (($elems.length % n) != 0) {
      $(panelHtml).insertAfter(parent+">"+children+":last");
    }

}
separateRows(".team-members", ".team-member");
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach using `filter()` and compare current element to `next()` element offset (if next element exists)

```
function separateRows(parent, children) {
  var panelHtml = '\
            <div class="team-member__panel"> \
            </div> \
        ';

  $(parent).children(children).filter(function(i) {
    var $el = $(this), $next = $el.next();
    // if no $next is last element and needs separator
    return !$next.length || $next.offset().top > $el.offset().top;
  }).after(panelHtml);


}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zbqq782m/4/)**</kbd>